# How to extract a smaller list of a list between two specified indexes in java

Tags: java, arraylist

what is the best way to extract a smaller list of a list between two specified indexes 
here is the code for more explanation:

```
List<String> places = Arrays.asList("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata", "NY", "bla bla" );
List<String> modifiedPlaces ; // I need to get only  values from places[0] to  places[2]
```

so ***modifiedPlaces*** will be ("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `subList` method of java List.